# svc_tli_create not found in Linux

Tags: linux, function, linux-kernel

My application code calling function `svc_tli_create()` and it is running on UNIX.  Now I am porting the application codes to LINUX and this function is not there in LINUX. what is the LINUX equivalent function for UNIX function `svc_tli_create()` ?

Comment: can you describe the "svc_tli_create()"-function?

Comment: please refer link unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/svc_tli_create for "svc_tli_create()" description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`TI-RPC`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libtirpc/) provides a SUN compatible RPC interface and used by recent glibc as well.

Comment: please refer link http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/svc_tli_create/ for  "svc_tli_create()" description

Comment: this library libtirpc is not there in Linux

Comment: I will try to install package which gives these libraries and compile  my programs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the information about libtirpc!!.  I installed a package "libtirpc-0.1.7-9.fc7.x86_64.rpm" with the help of admin.  It created library libtirpc.so.1.0.7.  To include this .so file in Makefile created symbolic link to this as "ln -s  libtirpc.so.1 libtirpc.so" and included in Makefile.  And the error for "svc_tli_create" is cleared now.